# How to import js file from cdn?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, pdf.js

How do we import js file from cdn?
I am building a custom component (a wrapper component) to view the pdf files. and for this I need to use pdf.js file from cdn and I am unable to import the file?

following does not work

```
import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.228/pdf.min.js";
```

Comment: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf

Comment: @Dan I want to build my own wrapper component.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cdn-plugin

Comment: and there has doc in vue official docs if want to build your app as component lib. that is one kind of build option.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally include it in your index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.228/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can use an npm library e.g  [vue-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf)

install it into your modules

`npm install --save vue-pdf`

and use it

`import pdf from 'vue-pdf'`

Answer (score -1):

To import the **JS file from CDN** and use in **vue.js component**, you can use **mounted lifecycle** and there you need to append your script into DOM.

Then it will be available into your **window** global variable.

**Working code example:**

```
mounted () {
  let pdfJS = document.createElement('script')
  pdfJS.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.228/pdf.min.js')
  document.head.appendChild(pdfJS)
  // for checking whether it's loaded in windows are not, I am calling the below function.
  this.checkPDFJSLib()
},
methods: {
  checkPDFJSLib() {
    console.log(window.pdfjsLib)
  }
}
```